# batik converting two svg to a single pdf

Tags: java, pdf, svg, batik

I'm trying to use `Batik` to do the following task:

I have few set of `SVGs graphs`, I need to create one `.PDF` file which basically has some `texts` followed by a `SVG converted graph` then few more `text` followed by another `SVG converted graph` and so on.

stupidly I tried this but with no surprise the second transcoder gets ignored(no Exception), I'm not sure how to tackle this:

```
Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(new File(DESKTOP + "svg1.svg")));
TranscoderInput transcoderInput1 = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(new File(DESKTOP + "svg2.svg")));;
TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File(DESKTOP+"results.pdf")));
transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);
transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput1, transcoderOutput);
```

so in short I have two problems:

1. How to add few SVG into a .PDF?
2. How to add text along side them?

Comment: `it just doesn't work` is not a helpful description of what's going wrong. Please be more precise.

Comment: @germi well, I was hoping that the second transcode continues to write on the same output stream, but unfortunately it doesn't. is simply ignore the computation of  **transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput1, transcoderOutput);** ( no exception)

Comment: Use something like apache fop that already uses batik and is meant for layout of pages and text content and images and tables and more

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new svg with these two svg files side by side or upside down, then convert new svg to .pdf file.

or

if you want to create two svg file as two different pages in a single pdf file, then convert these two svg file to pdf files then merge two pdf files to single pdf file with itext 2.1.7(open source) or ghostscript